# Error when using STR() function when executing a SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl

**Data**

```
<ns0:Address rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">s block, kotahena</ns0:Address>
```

**SPARQL Query:**

```
"PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>" +
                    "PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> " +
                    "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> " +
                    "PREFIX ns0: <http://www.Jobsurveillance.com/CV#> " +
                    "SELECT (str(?object) as ?label) WHERE { " +
                    " ?subject rdf:Full_Name ?object ." +
                    "}"
```

**Error during Run**
Exception error occurs when running the program.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryParseException: Encountered "(" at line 1, column 212.
Was expecting one of:
<VAR1> ...
<VAR2> ...
"distinct" ...
"reduced" ...
"*" ...
```

Comment: **1)** You're using an ancient Jena version (latest is 3.7.0 - why are you using 2.x?) **2)** which brings me to the point, that next time you should mention that you're using Apache Jena! **3)** Update the version and it will work **4)** `rdf:Full_Name` -> don't do this, the `rdf` namespace is a reserved vocabulary - use your own namespace.

Comment: Given what you called the *data* - which in fact is just a single line from an RDF/XML document - how is this related to the SPARQL query? I mean, clearly the query doesn't much the data...

Comment: ancient Jena, maybe it does not support SPARQL1.1 fully

Comment: `Encountered "("` -- this is before the `str` so `str()` is not relevant.  Looks like a very old Jena with SPARQL 1.0 default parser.

Comment: Issue fixed by upgrading the version of Jene. Thanks everyone for your help!!